# How to make two slides on the sides in Swiper coverflow

Tags: swiper.js

I have a Swiper slider with coverflow effect I need to make sure that two slides are on the sides and the active one is in the middle

Now the problem is that initially everything is correct, but when I scroll to the next slide, one slide is shown on the right, but there should be two on the sides

```js
 const sectionCarouselSliderSlider = new Swiper('.section-carousel-slider__slider', {
      loop: true,
      paginationClickable: true,
      effect: 'coverflow',
      grabCursor: true,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 0,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 2.5,
        slideShadows: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.carousel-slider__next',
        prevEl: '.carousel-slider__prev',
      },
    });
  });
```

```css
.section-carousel-slider__slider {
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 590px;
}


.swiper-slide {
  width: 37rem;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KUqc.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76g18.png)